# display first item jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list that is kind of like this:

```
<li class="listElement semiUniqueCLassOne" unique-class="semiUniqueCLassOne" style="display:none;">one</li>
<li class="listElement semiUniqueCLassOne" unique-class="semiUniqueCLassOne" style="display:none;">two</li>
<li class="listElement semiUniqueCLassOne" unique-class="semiUniqueCLassOne" style="display:none;">three</li>
<li class="listElement semiUniqueCLassTwo" unique-class="semiUniqueCLassTwo" style="display:none;">four</li>
<li class="listElement semiUniqueCLassTwo" unique-class="semiUniqueCLassTwo" style="display:none;">five</li>
<li class="listElement semiUniqueCLassThree" unique-class="semiUniqueCLassThree" style="display:none;">six</li>
```

I'm trying to only show the first of each of the `semiUniqueCLass` so I'm attempting to do it like this:

```
$('.listElement').each(function(){
    var uniqueClass = $(this).attr('unique-class');
    if($('.'+uniqueClass).is(':first')){
        $(this).show();
    }
});
```

this doesn't work... what ways can I make it work? tried several, a bit stuck.

Comment: When you say "first" do you mean you want the first of each: semiUniqueCLassOne, semiUniqueCLassTwo, semiUniqueCLassThree?

Comment: Yeah, exactly, the first of semiUniqueCLassOne should show, the first of  semiUniqueCLassTwo should show and the first of semiUniqueCLassThree

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the [***.first()***](http://api.jquery.com/first/) method.

```
$('.listElement').each(function(){
    var uniqueClass = $(this).attr('unique-class');
    $('.'+uniqueClass).first().show();
});
```

***[And the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hZv8h/)***.

Another solution is shown as below:

```
var clazzs = $('.listElement').map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('unique-class');
});

$.unique(clazzs).each(function() {
  $('.'+this).first().show();
});
```

***[Also the working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hZv8h/2/)***.

Comment: Not very efficient code, though. It will show the first item for as many items as there is.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine What about the second solution?

Comment: Nice. Maybe not the most efficient, but definitely a concise solution.

Comment: [benchmark](http://jsperf.com/select-first-of-each-class) :) the good news is that the second method *is* faster.

Comment: Second solution worked perfect! Thanks so much! Sorry for the delayed Answer Accept. I fell asleep at my desk ahaha.

Answer (score 5):

This should do the trick:

```
$('.listElement').hide();
$('.listElement:first-child').show();
```

If there's more elements with the `listElement` class:

```
$('.listElement[@class*=semiUniqueCLass]').hide();
$('.listElement[@class*=semiUniqueCLass]:first-child').show();
```

(Only shows / hides `listElement`s that have a `class` that *contains* `semiUniqueCLass`)

To show the first of each *unique* `semiUniqueCLass*` item, take a look at [Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack)'s [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621334/1835379) or [xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/762073/xdazz)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621199/1835379).

Comment: Look at the code again; `semiUniqueClass` is not a class. Your selector doesn't work.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Whoops, fixed.

Comment: It still doesn't answer correctly the answer. Clearly, OP's asking as if he had other `listElement`, but only wants to show the first `semiUniqueClass` and hide the other `semiUniqueClass` only (not the other `listElement`).

Comment: Not sure the regex is correct though, I'm not proficient enough with jQuery selectors :-). But OP's code shows `semiUniqueClassOne`, etc, in the `unique-class` attribute.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: `class="listElement semiUniqueCLassOne"`, Should work, methinks. Also, nitpicking, but this's a selector, not a regex ;)

Comment: @xdazz: [Please read the MDN documentation on `:first-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:first-child)

Comment: I'm afraid your code will hide all the elements starting with `semiUniqueClass` but the first, even though OP would want to show only the first of *each* semiUniqueClass. i.e. he'll want to hide the first of `semiUniqueClassOne`, the first of `semiUniqueClassSecond`, etc.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, I know what `:first-child` is, but the op is not want to show the first child of the parent, but the first element of each matched elements, as @Florian said.

Comment: @FlorianMargaine: Ah, yea, I see that now, must've read over it.
I'll point to Jack's answer, since that works. No need to duplicate code.

Answer (score 2):

To show the first of each *unique* `semiUniqueCLass*` item, you'd have to iterate over all relevant `.listElement` nodes manually:

```
var shown = {}; // keep track of which class has already been shown

$('.listElement[unique-class]').each(function() {
  var className = this.getAttribute('unique-class');

  if (!shown[className]) {
    // this class has not been seen before, show the first only
    shown[className] = true;
    $(this).show();
  }
});
```

It shows elements `one`, `four` and `six`.

**Update**

I've pitted this answer against the [two solutions by xdazz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621199/1338292) using [this jsperf benchmark](http://jsperf.com/select-first-of-each-class). This answer comes out on top with the runner up being ~30% slower (in Chrome).

Comment: For a maybe better answer, you could put the class in jQuery's selector. This way, no need to check for matches.

Answer (score -1):

This code shows the first item :

```
$('[class^=listElement]').first().show();
```

Comment: Because it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14621132/display-first-item-jquery/14621253#comment20419699_14621149

Comment: why are you pointing to `listElement` OP wants to show all unique classes first of these `[semiUniqueCLassOne, semiUniqueCLasstwo, semiUniqueCLassthree]` did you got the point?